# How to turn off "usages" feature of Android Studio Flamingo on Mac

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2 on Mac, I've noticed that in Java (at least), for class level variables and methods, they have a new feature where it shows the number of usages:

[image]

I don't want this feature as it adds cognitive load to reading code.  How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio on **Windows**:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints
```

and there is a checkbox "Usages".

or you can right click on "Usages" in your code and you will get a drop down menu

[image]

Android Studio for **Mac**:

1. Go to “Preference”
2. Search “code vision”
3. Go under Editor > Inlay
4. Hints Under “Code vision”, uncheck “Usages” option.

Taken from [here](https://medium.com/@life-is-short-so-enjoy-it/intellij-idea-how-to-hide-code-usage-f1b2340773a2)

Comment: I'm not getting this same behavior.  Unchecking the box at Android Studio \ Settings \ Editor \ Inlay Hints \ Code Vision \ Usages seems to have no effect (seems like a bug) and I can only successfully change the position from top to right which is a little bit better.  I've updated the question to be more precise about my version.

Comment: @NerdyBunz
I've updated the answer, also added a link to the Medium article. The guy seems to have the same problem. Check it.